# How do you solve this fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

> What is the value of:
>   $$ \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{16} $$

**My answer:** $ \dfrac{1}{48} $ .
I believe that it's incorrect.

Three does not divide into $16$, so I cross multiplied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{32}{48}-\frac{3}{48}$

Comment: They're addition, not subtraction. It is negative one over 16. Can you break it down for me? I've tried all the methods I know of for this one. Cross Multiply.  I get 1 over 48... Is this correct?

Comment: you have negative numerator in \frac{-1,16}

Comment: Adding negative one over 16 is the same as subtracting (positive) one over 16.

Comment: TI don't understand? I'm trying to add the fractions not subtract. When you add -1 to 2 you get 1..They never taught us this in class  just handed us this packet and they are hard. I keep getting wrong answers.

Comment: You cannot simply add the numerators *until* you have made the denominators equal.

Comment: Well I know that already. I came up with the LCD (or cd??) of 48. I got an answer of 1 over 48.

Comment: “cross multiplication” is a technique that makes sense only when you have an equation, which you don’t.

Comment: You should know that: $$\frac {-x} {y} = \frac {x} {-y} = -\frac {x}{y}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac23+\frac{-1}{16}=\left(\frac23\times 1\right)\!+\!\left(\frac{-1}{16}\times 1\right)=\left(\frac23\times\frac{16}{16}\right)\!+\!\left(\frac{-1}{16}\times\frac{3}{3}\right)=\frac{32}{48}+\frac{-3}{48}=\frac{32-3}{48}=\frac{29}{48}$$

Comment: That was the answer Wolfram gave me. Where do you derive this x 1 past the first equals sign? How does it become a numerator of 16 on the right fraction just past the second equals sign? If only I could understand how this is done.  I'm really really confused with this one. Many questions come to mind. What is the significance of 16/16 past the second equals sign (sorry my \func isn't working)

Comment: Let me explain using a different problem.  Let's say I have two similar cakes.  The first one is divided into two equal slices and the other one is divided into three equal slices.  I get one slice from the first cake and another slice from the second cake.  But I can't add the slice from the first cake with the slice in the second cake because they have different sizes.  So I cut each slice of the first cake into 3 and I cut each slice of the second cake into 2.  Each cake now has slices of the same size (1/6 of the cake).

Comment: The story in my comment above can be written in a shorter way like this: $\frac12+\frac13=(\frac12\times\frac33)+(\frac13\times\frac22)=\frac36+\frac26$.  Does this make things clearer?

Comment: I finally figured out the "what you do to the top you must do to the bottom" rule. Which may explain why you do $\frac{16}{16}$ and $\frac{3}{3}$  after the second equal sign. I am still figuring it out.

Comment: I did this one for a trial run:
$\frac{2}{7} + \frac{8}{14} = (\frac{2}{7} * \frac{14}{14}) + (\frac{8}{14} * \frac{7}{7}) = \frac{28}{98} + \frac{56}{98} = \frac{84}{98} = \frac{6}{7}$ Which was correct. It looks like I can do it. Needs more practice because it is not efficient yet.

Comment: This method does not appear to work for this one: $\frac{3}{8} + \frac{5}{6}$ I get a denominator of 48 but the numerators are incorrect. I see WolframAlpha says my denominator should be 24 (which is half of 48).

Comment: $\frac38+\frac56=(\frac38\times\frac66)+(\frac56\times\frac{8}{8})=\frac{18}{48}+\frac{40}{48}=\frac{58}{48}=\frac{29\times 2}{24\times 2}=\frac{29}{24}\times\frac22=\frac{29}{24}\times 1=\frac{29}{24}$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{3}+\frac{-1}{16}&=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{16} \\
&=\left(\frac{16}{16}\right)\times\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{16}\times\left(\frac{3}{3}\right) \\
&=\frac{32}{48}-\frac{3}{48} \\
&=\frac{29}{48}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Since $3$ and $16=2^4$ are [*coprime*](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Mutually-prime_numbers), their least common multiple (this is the common denominator) is their product $3\cdot 16=48$. Hence:

$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{16}=
\frac{2\color{red}{\cdot 16}}{3\color{red}{\cdot 16}}-\frac{1\color{magenta}{\cdot 3}}{16\color{magenta}{\cdot 3}}=
\frac{32}{48}-\frac{3}{48}=\frac{32-3}{48}=\frac{29}{48}.$$

Now $29$ and $48$ are again coprime, so we cannot simplify further.